# Are there any plug-ins or software programs (preferably free) that you use to generate MathJax equations and edit them?

Tags: support, mathjax, editor

It's taking me a very long time to ask questions and respond on here, just because I'm having a hard time figuring out the syntax... Do any of you have suggestions?

Comment: continue to try you'll get used with the time :). Also a good thing to learn is to look at others syntax by clicking the edit button. Actually you have here (on MSE) a HUGE pool of examples :).

Comment: The old adage: Practice practice practice. Let me throw in [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).

Comment: @Surb Ah... so that really is what it boils down to, eh? I suppose I am already getting the hang of it a bit. I've only just started figuring it out yesterday. That's a good tip, looking at others' syntax through the edit button.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Thanks! This will definitely come in handy.

Comment: You might try have a look on older questions tagged [mathjax+editor](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathjax+editor).

Comment: @MartinSleziak I didn't realize there was such a tag... thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an online editor may be helpful as you are beginning to learn the syntax. There are several editors listed [in this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mathjax-users/BZeCIvhEpO4).

After a quick glance, I like [HostMath](http://www.hostmath.com/) interface; it which offers palettes that get you over syntactical hurdles and leaves it for you to fill them in. (I don't use this, or any such editor myself.)

Comment: What does WYSIWEG stand for? This is very helpful, thanks. @1999

Comment: @Keenan, the intended acronym was probably [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG)

Comment: I built SaturnAPI to include Octave and MathJax. Check it out: https://saturnapi.com/fullstack/equations-and-matrices